# removing string where it exists elsewhere in the column r

Tags: r, dataframe, split, sapply

I have a dataframe with strings of names:

```
df =data.frame("names" = c("George Orwell; Ayn Rand; Adam Smith", "George Orwell; Rand; Orwell"))
df
                                names
1 George Orwell; Ayn Rand; Adam Smith
2         George Orwell; Rand; Orwell
```

I'd like to remove all the repeat names, so that each list has only the unique names. Where there is only a last name, I'd like to keep the last name if it's unique but remove it if there's an instance of the full name in the same string. So the result for the df above would be:

```
                                names
1 George Orwell; Ayn Rand; Adam Smith
2                 George Orwell; Rand
```

I am able to keep only unique values with:

```
sapply(strsplit(df$names, ";\\s*"), function(z) paste(unique(z), collapse = "; "))
[1] "George Orwell; Ayn Rand; Adam Smith" "George Orwell; Rand; Orwell"
```

but this keeps "Orwell" in df$names[2].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, we can `gsub` away everything but last name and `paste` only  `!duplicated` flagged parts. Also works with middle names (but will probably fail with two-part surnames without hyphens).

```
strsplit(x, ';\\s+') |> sapply(\(.) paste(.[!duplicated(gsub('.+\\s', '', .))], collapse='; '))
# [1] "George Orwell; Ayn Rand; Adam Smith" "George Orwell; Rand"                
# [3] "Michael J Fox; Rand"
```

---

*Data:*

```
x <- c("George Orwell; Ayn Rand; Adam Smith", "George Orwell; Rand; Orwell", 
"Michael J Fox; Rand; Fox")
```

Answer (score 0):

though this is not the efficient answer but an alternate approach

```r
df %>% mutate(row=row_number()) %>% separate_rows(names, sep = ';', convert = T) %>% 
  mutate(names=trimws(names)) %>% 
  separate(names, c('first','last'), sep='\\s', remove = F, fill = 'left') %>% 
  group_by(row,last) %>% slice_head(n=1) %>% ungroup() %>% 
  group_by(row) %>% 
  mutate(names=paste0(names, collapse = ';')) %>% slice_head(n=1) %>% ungroup %>% 
  select(names)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
# A tibble: 2 × 1
  names                            
  <chr>                            
1 George Orwell;Ayn Rand;Adam Smith
2 George Orwell;Rand
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

This script will identify dupes by last name, but retrieve the longer name in each case.

```r
df <- data.frame("names" = c("George Orwell; Ayn Rand; Adam Smith", "George Orwell; Rand; Orwell"))

fullnames <- strsplit(df$names, "; +")
lastnames <- lapply(strsplit(df$names, "; +"), \(x) gsub(".* ([^ ]+)", "\\1", x))
elements <- lapply(lastnames, \(x)as.integer(factor(x)))

df$names2 <- sapply(FUN = paste, collapse = "; ",
  mapply(fullnames, elements, FUN = \(name, elem)  
       sapply(unique(elem), \(i) name[elem=i][which.max(nchar(name[elem==i]))])))

df
#>                                 names                              names2
#> 1 George Orwell; Ayn Rand; Adam Smith George Orwell; Ayn Rand; Adam Smith
#> 2         George Orwell; Rand; Orwell                 George Orwell; Rand
```